get mime type and extension of image in variable or file without extension
I have telegram bot receiving a photo in webhook. I can download photo but not get file extension. How to get image extension and optionally mime-type from variable containing photo?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type

@MarkusZeller this get info from file, how about variable? And file extension from mime type?

What variable? When you know the mime type you can do a mapping to the extension.

You can use the buffer method on an finfo instance to get the mime type of an arbitrary string blob if you don't want to write it to disk first:
// Just a small image from http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever
$blob = base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==');

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->buffer($blob) . "\n";

// Result: image/gif; charset=binary

Demo: https://3v4l.org/EJ95S
